# Java replace the last character "+" with ";" of the groups of string that match

Tags: java, regex

I have a file which contains:

```
....
XPS430_1 + XPS430_3 + XPS430_5 + XPS430_7 + XPS430_9 + XPS430_11 + XPS430_13 + XPS430_15 + 
XPS830_1 + XPS830_3 + XPS830_5 + XPS830_7 + XPS830_9 + XPS830_11 + XPS830_13 + XPS830_15 + 
XPS751_1 + XPS751_3 + XPS751_5 + XPS751_7 + XPS751_9 + XPS751_11 + XPS751_13 + XPS751_15 "+"
group XpsEvenPins = ....
```

and I would like to replace the last `"+"` with `";"`
I have multiple occurrences of "group", and I would like to ends-up with `";"`

Thanks

Tried several `matcher.replace` and other string manipulation without success. I don't know how to replace only the last `"+"`?

Comment: Is that plus you want to replace actually inside quotes or is that just you trying to highlight it? If those quotes exist you could just do `replace("\"+\"", ";");` edit: Or if those quotes aren't there but it is always `+ group` a simple `replace("+ group", "; group");` could work.

Comment: the quotes just to highlight which + i want to replace with ;

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("a+b+c+".replaceFirst("(.*)\+", "$1;")); // a+b+c;